# this.ref.detectChanges() required all over my application in order to prevent infinite loading

Tags: angular

I have a c# api backend and a separate angular2 application front end.
I have different pages in the angular and almost every page has a loader and almost all of those pages will load infinitely.  The only thing that can stop the loading is   this.ref.detectChanges();
So I keep doing that everywhere.  But I think that sounds backwards and not necessary.  Can someone advise if there is likely to be a bigger issue?

(same as scope.apply in angular1)

this.ref.detectChanges();

examples from two different .ts pages:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.Loadfirstmethod();
        this.Loadsecondmethod();
        this.LoadRules();
        this.ref.detectChanges();




ngOnInit() {
    this.titleService.setTitle('title | Dashboard');
    // getting user permission if available in local storage
    if (localStorage.getItem('userpermission') !== null) {
        localStorage.setItem('currApp', 'Dashboard');
        this.userpermission = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userpermission'));

    } else {
        // using mediator service for getting the user permission value
        this._loginMediatorService.getPermission.subscribe(async userparam => {
            this.userpermission = await userparam;
            this.ref.detectChanges();
            localStorage.setItem('currApp', 'Dashboard');
        },
            error => this.msg = <any>error);
    }
    // getting modules name
    this.arrModulesName = this.moduleService.getModuleName();

}
```

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem in a stackblitz. It seems you're using observables emitting promises, which is really looking for trouble. Why do that? Also, why load data from ngAfterViewInit()?

Comment: In general you should no have to do what you are doing.

Comment: how should I change the posted code to return a promise?

Comment: You shouldn't return promises in general. Favor observables. And the above code is very partial, so it's quite hard understanding what the problem is, what it's supposed to do, and how it should be written. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem in a stackblitz.